# What do the native speakers say for the indian expression "I have a head bath today"

Tags: word-choice

i have heard expressionsions like I have a total bath or I have a head  bath. i think native speakers saythat I have washed my hair in the similar instance. what are the other possible expressions

Comment: This [site](https://www.englishpractice.com/common-mistakes/common-errors-esl-english/) says "When an Indian speaker says that he has a head-bath every day, what he means is that he washes his head or hair every day."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bathing is very dependent on culture. Indians and English don't bathe the same way.

Most adults take a daily shower in the morning, and wash their hair in the shower. If by "head bath" you mean "washing your hair" then this is the answer to your question.

But this is not seen as a particularly significant or special thing. There are lots of rules and expectations of when it is okay to take a "head bath" and when it is not. So "wash my hair" is the right way to say "head bath", but it doesn't carry that expression's cultural baggage.

> I washed my hair this morning and I can't do a thing with it.
>
> Kids! Into the shower right now, and don't forget to wash your hair.
>
> I ran a bath and laid in it for an hour.
>
> I don't wash my hair every morning, but I always brush my teeth.

Comment: Few adults that I know...  I mean I ripped out my bathtub as a waste of space.